# PostgreSQL: как провести операцию insert с on conflict?

Tags: postgresql, insert

Имеется таблица:

```
 aircraft_code | seat_no | fare_conditions 
---------------+---------+-----------------
 319           | 2A      | Business
 319           | 2C      | Business
 319           | 2D      | Business
```

Нужно провести две операции `insert on conflict`: с использованием перечисления имён столбцов для проверки дублирования, а также с использованием `on constraint' (ограничение должно наклажываться на составной ключ, состоящий из двух столбцов) Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А где здесь первичный ключ?  Где `CONSTRAINT`?

Comment: первичный ключ здесь составной, включает в себя первые два стобца

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не указали, что за `CONSTRAINT`, поэтому вот вам фантазия
на тему:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (
  aircraft_code   INTEGER
, seat_no         TEXT
, fare_conditions TEXT

, CONSTRAINT t_pkey PRIMARY KEY (aircraft_code, seat_no)
)
;

INSERT INTO t
  (aircraft_code, seat_no, fare_conditions)
VALUES
  (          319,    '2D',       'Economy')
    ON CONFLICT (aircraft_code, seat_no) DO
UPDATE
   SET fare_conditions = EXCLUDED.fare_conditions
;

INSERT INTO t
  (aircraft_code, seat_no, fare_conditions)
VALUES
  (          319,    '2D',      'Business')
    ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT t_pkey DO
UPDATE
   SET fare_conditions = EXCLUDED.fare_conditions
;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это было то, что нужно.

Comment: @Froman  Не за что.  Не забывайте голосовать за ответы и принимать их как верные, нажав галочку.